# How to copy data from file to another file starting from specific line

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have two files `data.txt` and `results.txt`, assuming there are 5 lines in `data.txt`, I want to copy all these lines and paste them in file `results.txt` starting from the line number **4**.

Here is a sample below:

**Data.txt file:**

```
stack
ping
dns
ip
remote
```

**Results.txt file:**

```
# here are some text
# please do not edit these lines
# blah blah..
this is the 4th line that data should go on.
```

I've tried `sed` with various combinations but I couldn't make it work, I'm not sure if it fit for that purpose as well.

```
sed -n '4p' /path/to/file/data.txt > /path/to/file/results.txt
```

The above code copies line 4 only. That isn't what I'm trying to achieve. As I said above, I need to copy all lines from `data.txt` and paste them in `results.txt` but it has to start from line 4 without modifying or overriding the first 3 lines.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

> I want to override the copied data starting from line number **4** in
>   the file *results.txt*. So, I want to leave the first 3 lines without
>   modifications and override the rest of the file with the data copied
>   from `data.txt` file.

Comment: An easy solution would be to have an additional "header" file that contains the first three lines that would would cat with the other input file into the result file. I'm still looking for a way to do what you ask though, it's definitely feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way that works well from cron.  Less chance of losing data or corrupting the file:

```
# preserve first lines of results
head -3 results.txt > results.TMP

# append new data
cat data.txt >> results.TMP

# rename output file atomically in case of system crash
mv results.TMP results.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked really well. I take this as an accepted answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  The `.TMP` technique is something I use heavily in my own scripts in a variety of situations.  Most of them, atomic update aside, due to the nature of the update, can't modify in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use process substitution to give `cat` a fifo which it will be able to read from :

```
cat <(head -3 result.txt) data.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I greatly appreciate it. But unfortunately it didn't work, it override the first 3 lines which I want to keep unmodified. Craig Estey's answer worked for me. Thank you again.

Comment: @JerryB That's strange, I tried it on Cygwin and it worked all right. Was there anything remarkable about the first three lines of the resulting file?

Comment: I tried again now with your exact code but it override the first 3 lines again. I tried with the double arrows `>>`, so it kept the 3 lines this time but it duplicated them and every tine the script runs it doubles the first 3 lines and the copied lines as well. I'm not sure actually what makes it not working. But I have to thank you very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the file is being overwritten before it is read by the subprocess, thus the `head` returning nothing and the result only containing the data file. I don't know what causes it though... You're very welcome, and thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

```
head -n 3 /path/to/file/results.txt > /path/to/file/results.txt
cat /path/to/file/data.txt >> /path/to/file/results.txt
```

Comment: That didn't work. It removed the first 3 lines from results.txt. I want to leave them un-modified and override the rest of the lines. I have edited my question, please take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use awk:

```
awk 'NR!=FNR || NR<4' Result.txt Data.txt
```